# pass string with $_POST

Tags: php

I created a search function in php. I use an input field and pass the variable to the search function. However, I'm facing an issue when the search input string contains more than one word, e.g. "New York". In this case only New is passed and therefore no results can be found. I now that a string need to be enclosed in "", but something I'm doing wrong. Can you please support me?

Thats the input fiedl of input.

```
td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="' . $city .'" value=""/></td>
```

and then I pass this variable to this code:

```
$address = $_POST['address'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];
$url = "https://example.com/get_search_product/?address=" . $address . "&distance=" . $distance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provided that your $address is actually "New York"

```
$address = urlencode($address)
```

New York has a space and if you want to construct a url in that manner, you'll need to convert that to New+York

Answer (score 0):

You want to create url string. It should not have space between them. Otherwise value to parameters will be broken by spaces. Hence, as a result, you get only first word.

Solution: Either replace spaces by '+' or by '%20'. Or use `urlencode($address)` on complete `$url` to replace all special characters by their URL Encoded characters.

```
$address = $_POST['address'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];
$url = "https://example.com/get_search_product/?address=" . $address . "&distance=" . $distance;
$url = urlencode($url); //add this
```

Refer:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Happy Coding !